# Currently using an iframe as a glorified script tag (sandboxing my JavaScript code). Can I use a worker, sharedworker or similar instead?

Tags: javascript, iframe, web-worker

I am writing an integration that needs to run as a third party script on a host page. It needs to be on the same domain as my API for optimal CORS configuration and not requiring `OPTIONS` calls. It needs to have it's own CSP and it needs to communicate to the host page.

Right now I achieve this through the use of an `iframe`. The issue with an `iframe` is it loads an entire document only to be used to load a single JS file.

Is it possible to load a JavaScript file directly from a different origin and run it in a sandbox?

Comment: The iframe is the best way to sandbox it. That's how Stack Snippet works, that's how jsfiddle works.

Comment: Can you put an iframe in the head element?

Comment: "*The issue with an iframe is it loads an entire document only to be used to load a single JS file.*" A Worker also comes with big tradeoffs. Starting the whole context, its own event-loop etc. **and** it offers only very limited protection (basically your users just won't be able to mess with your DOM). Stick to the iframe. "*Can you put an iframe in the head element*" Why would you do that?